# Return different values instead of undefined when key isn't found in an object

Tags: javascript, object, prototypejs, undefined

I'd like to set a property to an object using prototype, if it's possible, so that when I try to get an undefined value, it returns a default instead of `undefined`, like:

```
obj = {
  lang : {en: 'hello', it:'ciao'}
}
```

Example 1: `obj.lang.es` (`undefined`) - I'd like to get `obj.lang.en` instead of `undefined`.

Example 2: `obj.something.else` - I'd like to get `false` instead of an error because it can't read else of `undefined`.

Comment: Don't do that, write a proper getter function instead.

Comment: Or just inline it if you are only going to use that in one place: `var s = obj.lang.es || obj.lang.en`.

Comment: You generally don't want to touch Object.prototype - this will change arrays, dates and everything else derrived from Object. consider building functions that will take an object as argument and return what you need instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask : "If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!".

Comment: just i was not ready, then i forgot. thnk for the notify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably not a good idea.
Better use a root or default key:

```
obj = {
    lang : {root: 'hello', en: 'hello', it:'ciao'}
}
```

So you can ask for a lang in this way:

```
var hi = obj.lang.es || obj.lang.root;
```

You can use this in combination with a getter method:

```
var getTranslation = function(lang) {
    return obj.lang[lang] || obj.lang.root;
};
var hi = getTranslation("es");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a pretty solution, but here it goes, create a prototype object that for any language defers the result to a default language. Then your particular object inherits from that prototype object and overrides any value it wants.

```
var languages = ['en', 'it', 'es']; // fill with every language you will ever use
var defaultLang = 'en';

var protoLang = Object.create(null);
function getDefaultLanguage(){
  return this[defaultLang];
}
languages.forEach(function(language){
  Object.defineProperty(protoLang, language, {
    get : getDefaultLanguage
  });
});


var obj = {
  lang : Object.create(protoLang, {
    en : { value : 'hello' },
    it : { value : 'ciao' }
  })
};


obj.lang.es // "hello"
obj.lang.en // "hello"
obj.lang.it // "ciao"
```

The thing is that you have to define every property first, that is why you need the languages array.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @DCoder. Maybe something like this:

```
function getLang(lang) {
    var result = this.obj[lang];
    if ( typeof result == 'undefined' ) {
        result = this.obj.en;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `;` inside object, there no content in `obj.lang`, instead try it like this:

```
obj = {
  lang: {en: 'hello', it: 'ciao'}
};

if (obj.lang.hasOwnProperty("en")) {
  console.log(obj.lang.en);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _No need `;` inside_. Read OP question carefully.